# Tridion page review

Tags: dxa, content-delivery, dxa-1.7

We have a requirement to provide the production URL to the client, as they don't have preview internal page access, and let the client review the prod page before we finally mark it as ready for all. How can we achieve this in Tridion?

Comment: Your requirement is not really clear to me.  Sounds a bit like a typical Staging / Live configuration?

Comment: The client want to review the content page in prod region, as they cannot access the lower region page externally. Once they review it in prod region, then only they want us to release it for public use. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, and that's why you'd normally setup a "Staging" environment - potentially with Experience Manager enabled, but let's go one step at a time...

Answer (score 4):

What Rick had suspected, you have confirmed with you comment, this is indeed a typical staging/live setup. That means, that for a single CM environment (Production) you have 2 delivery environments (Staging and Live). They both have their own Content Delivery stack and Content Data Store, and you can publish to either of them independently from the other.

Because Staging is not publicly available, one of the main reasons for using it is indeed reviewing. And because you're publishing from the same CM environment, the same templating and content is used, so the resulting item on the staging site will be as close to the live one as possible. Once the reviewer is satisfied with the outcome, the same item can be published to live, making it publicly accessible to others.

You have tagged the question DXA 1.7, so I'm guessing you're using Web 8 or higher (SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 is only supported up to DXA version 1.6.). See the following links for additional information and how to achieve this in Web 8+:

- [DTAP environment](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-77DF6F6E-56D5-4599-9164-64A454DB26B3&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-98FBCCB2-B259-4841-A8F4-9EAC58C5484F.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-77DF6F6E-56D5-4599-9164-64A454DB26B3&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Ddtap&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1553036735560&currentQuery=dtap&currentScope=)
- [Topology Manager Concepts](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-FAA9A349-213B-4892-B5AD-8D0D031A5AC8#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-AF20A2A9-709B-4D72-9278-06F99835192B.xml&docid=GUID-FAA9A349-213B-4892-B5AD-8D0D031A5AC8&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-FAA9A349-213B-4892-B5AD-8D0D031A5AC8)
- [Topology Manager How and Why](https://vimeo.com/175950249)

Answer (score 1):

Next to what Atila said, DXA also provides some specific support for Staging / Live configurations:

- It provides a pre-defined "Staging / Live" Business Process Type (and associated Topology Type)
- It ensures that XPM markup is output when publishing to "Staging", but not when publishing to "Live"

  - Experience Manager (XPM) is typically used for reviewing and in-context editing purposes on a "Staging" environment